# Hot Hide Glue Guidelines

Tags: glue, traditional-techniques

The instructions for my hot hide glue pearls say to keep the temperature at 60°C.

- How forgiving is the holding temperature? If you overheat the glue, at what point will it break down and lose its "glueyness"?
- How long can you cook it for?
- How many times can you reheat it (and add more fresh glue)?

Comment: Quick observation: It has been pointed out that wax pots are available on Amazon for less than most electric glue pots, and are functionally almost identical...

Comment: I use a small slow cooker that I picked up at a yardsale quite cheap. I inverted the lid, cut out a hole, and stuck in a little mason jar, so it acts as a double boiler. However, if I just let it sit, the temperature goes up to about 80°C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Lee Valley, where I bought my glue. This was their response:

> Holding temperature should be maintained accurately when using hide glue. Overheating it can lead to a decrease in its overall holding strength.
>
> Generally speaking, the glue can be held at temperature for a work day, then refrigerated overnight. You’ll have about 4 re-heating cycles before the glue starts to break down, at which point it should be discarded.